# syncdb not working in Django nonrel using django_mongodb_engine

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-nonrel, django-mongodb-engine

I have Django-nonrel(1.3), django toolbox and django mongodb engine installed and working. However, when I try to syncdb I get an error:

```
...django/db/models/fields/subclassing.py", line 28, in inner
return func(*args, **kwargs)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```